Accessing ModelDerivativeClient to access any of the API calls throws 401
I am extending the HubsBrowser example to delve into Model Derivative API. My end goal is to browse models in ACC via web application, and for the selected model, I want to be able to extract all properties in it using the FetchSpecificPropertiesAsync API call. These are the steps I have done so far:

Following HubsBrowser, I am able to get a 3-legged token, browse my project/folders/files
When I click on a specific version of file, the viewer shows it (same as HubsBrowser example)
Now I am using the InternalToken and calling the ModelDerivative API's GetManifestAsync with the base64 URN of my object(file urn). This is where the problem is. I get the 401 error.

Question: Am I wrong to assume that since I am accessing an ACC file, the translation is already done and that I dont need to do translation or access the bucket etc?! My understanding is given the urn of the file in ACC, I would be able to access it's manifest. If that is not right, how do I go about it? Am I missing any scope for Model derivative API to work?
Following are the scopes I have:

Controller code:
 [HttpGet("{objectId}/modelviews")]
 public async Task<ActionResult> GetModelViews(string objectId)
 {
     //Eg objectId: urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.bOz5StqZQoqUqQLDlxdrSg
     var tokens = await AuthController.PrepareTokens(Request, Response, _aps);
     var modelViews = await _aps.GetManifestAsync(objectId, tokens);
     return Ok(modelViews);
 }

Service call code:
public partial class APS
{
    public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
    {
        var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes).TrimEnd('=');
    }

    public async Task<Manifest> GetManifestAsync(string objectId, Tokens tokens)
    {
        var modelDerivativesClient = new ModelDerivativeClient();
        var modelUrn = Base64Encode(objectId);

        try
        {
            var manifest = await modelDerivativesClient.GetManifestAsync(modelUrn, accessToken: tokens.InternalToken);
            return manifest;
        }
       
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            

        }
        return null;
        
    }
}

Error:
Unauthorized 401.


Ok, I figured the solution, Posting anyone who might be stuck with similar issue.

The token has to be PublicToken NOT InternalToken. This was causing the 401.
The objectId passed to the GetManifestAsync has to be the version of the model that was translated, which means, it is not the URN of the file, but the URN of the version itself. Eg: fileURN can be urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:C34W6MjMRY-ul8uoPhbRyQ, but the version that I am interested in is let's say v1 of this file. Its URN will be something like urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.C34W6MjMRY-ul8uoPhbRyQ?versionId=1 So the versionURN needs to be base64 encoded and passed to GetManifestAsync

